# Redirect particular subfolder under mod_dav_svn location

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

I am setting up an svn server using mod_dav_svn. I would like to satisfy all of the following:

- Collection of repositories resides at repos.example.com/ NOT repos.example.com/svn
- Non-svn content is available from the same server at repos.example.com/repo-style. This is to enable styling information. I am okay with the fact that I will not be able to have a repo with that name.

Here is the present configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName repos.example.com

  <Location />
    DAV svn

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Log In"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://***
    AuthLDAPBindDN ***
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
    require valid-user

    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPath /mnt/repos/svn
    SVNIndexXSLT /repo-style/svnindex.xsl
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /mnt/repos/svn-auth/access
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue with the above is that when a request comes in for repos.example.com/repo-admin mod_dav_svn replies saying that the repository does not exist. I need to concoct a rewrite scheme that isolates a request for that particular sub directory and serves regular html or php or whatever instead.

I have tried using re-writes or aliases to achieve this but have not been successful. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I get your question right, then you have two options:

First option is to give access to read files for everyone, but for write operations require authorized user. Config sample:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/svn

  # Authentication type, name, etc.

  # Authorization: Authenticated users only for non-read-only
  #                (write) operations; allow anonymous reads
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Learn more here: [Blanket access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.blanket)

Second option is to use AuthzSVNAccessFile. This option enables you to have more flexible per-directory and per-project access configuration. Sample config:

```
[groups]
admin = john, kate
devteam1 = john, rachel, sally
devteam2 = kate, peter, mark
docs = bob, jane, mike
training = zak

# Default access rule for ALL repositories
# Everyone can read, admins can write, Dan German is excluded.
[/]
* = r
@admin = rw
dangerman =

# Allow developers complete access to their project repos
[proj1:/]
@devteam1 = rw
[proj2:/]
@devteam2 = rw
[bigproj:/]
@devteam1 = rw
@devteam2 = rw
trevor = rw

# Give the doc people write access to all the docs folders
[/trunk/doc]
@docs = rw

# Give trainees write access in the training repository only
[TrainingRepos:/]
@training = rw
```

Learn more here: [How does AuthzSVNAccessFile work?](https://serverfault.com/a/159485/281189)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am afraid you misunderstood. My question is not about authorization but rather that I want a sub-folder which is not served by svn but is instead conventional html.

Comment: Hmm.. Well, I think it is even easier. I will update my answer tomorrow, because it is 2:28 am here and I want to sleep :) can you paste your full httpd.conf (apache config) file, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question on locations merging order](https://serverfault.com/questions/391457/how-does-apache-merge-multiple-matching-location-sections) about [Apache 2 sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/sections.html) in configuration, only a block declaring `<Location /repo-style>` may overwrite the declared `<Location />` delivering `DAV svn`.

As a `Directory` directive will not have priority, the only option is to deliver static content with a `Location` section, for instance thanks a CGI script quickly written in your favorite scripting langage.